# nodeclipse can't run package.json script targets

Tags: nodeclipse

with a simple package like

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "hello-world-server.njs",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node hello-world-server.js"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "keywords": [
    "node.js",
    "eclipse",
    "nodeclipse"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "readmeFilename": "README.md"
}
```

i can run (from command line) :

```
npm start
```

and all is fine. but from eclipse (nodeclipse), with npm ... , from the run configurations, all I get is:

```
> test@0.1.0 start /Users/chrismarx/Documents/workspaces/yardmap-3.5.0/test
> node ./hello-world-server.js

execvp(): No such file or directory
```

anybody know how to fix this? i just installed nodeclipse into a fresh install, i believe i've got the latest version  0.15.1.201404300203

Answer (score 1):

Usually in GUI select .js file, right-click Run As -> Node App.
Later can select from Run drop down menu

While `npm start` would be from command line.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can right click on /bin/www -> Run As -> Node App.